# iAdSuite bug leaves white space when ad disappears

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to incorporate the iAdSuite tab bar view implementation in my app and I'm seeing the same problem in the suite and my app. When the ad appears, my content's view is getting properly resized and the ad appears correctly. When the ad then disappears, it leaves behind white space where it was located. However, I've confirmed that my content view does get resized back to its original height and it gets drawn down to its original bounds. You just can't see the part where the ad was. I've made sure every view gets a layoutIfNeeded and just about everything else I can think of to no avail. Any thoughts?

[image]

Edit: I've figured out what the problem is. Apple's example apparently adds _bannerView to self.view every time showBannerView: is called but never removes the view. That still doesn't make complete sense since the banner view is being moved offscreen, but removing it does solve the white space problem. My solution is as follows, but if anyone has a more elegant way, let me know.

```
- (void)layoutAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
        _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    } else {
        _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    }

    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
    contentFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
    if (_bannerView.bannerLoaded) {
        contentFrame.size.height -= _bannerView.frame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    } else {
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.25 : 0.0 animations:^{
        _contentView.frame = contentFrame;
        [_contentView layoutIfNeeded];
        _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (!_bannerView.bannerLoaded) {
                             [_bannerView removeFromSuperview];
                             _bannerView=nil;
                         }
                     }];
}

- (void)showBannerView:(ADBannerView *)bannerView animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    _bannerView = bannerView;
    if (![self.view.subviews containsObject:_bannerView])
        [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];
    [self layoutAnimated:animated];
}

- (void)hideBannerView:(ADBannerView *)bannerView animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self layoutAnimated:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Removing the bannerview from the super view in the hideBannerView delegate method seems to have solved it.

```
- (void)hideBannerView:(ADBannerView *)bannerView animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self layoutAnimated:animated];
    [_bannerView removeFromSuperview];
    _bannerView = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this question and answer, I was pulling hairs with this one.
I changed the damn code like this and now the hiding animation works. I wonder why apple publishes  buggy sample code...

```
- (void)layoutAnimated:(BOOL)animated hide:(BOOL)hide
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
        _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    } else {
        _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    }

    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;


    CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
    if (!hide) {
        contentFrame.size.height -= _bannerView.frame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    } else {
        contentFrame.size.height += _bannerView.frame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.25 : 0.0 animations:^{
        _contentView.frame = contentFrame;
        [_contentView layoutIfNeeded];
        _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (hide) {
            [_bannerView removeFromSuperview];
            _bannerView=nil;
        }
    }];
}

- (void)showBannerView:(ADBannerView *)bannerView animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    _bannerView = bannerView;
    [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];
    [self layoutAnimated:animated hide:NO];
}

- (void)hideBannerView:(ADBannerView *)bannerView animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self layoutAnimated:animated hide:YES];

}
```